# Does number of impression on admob increases when i am testing my app in test mode?

Tags: android, admob

I am testing my android app in test mode and when i opened admob i see the total number of impression reached 14.Does that mean that the app was not running in test mode?If yes,will they ban my account?Should I create another account?I have not clicked on any ads..and my estimated earning remains zero as it should be..

Comment: Don't worry about it. That number is way too low for anyone to care about. The reason for the rule is so no one creates an app that automatically "clicks" ads so they can generate fake revenue and steal from AdMob and its advertisers. You're not clicking hundreds or thousands of ads, and in fact are only getting a fewimpressions, so no money exchanges hands. But it does sound like you're not in test mode.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have not published my app till now..should i publish my app without worrying about that impression count before publishing?

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. They have no idea you haven't published it yet. I had a few accidental ad clicks in my app with testing turned off before I published it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I am testing app in test mode will the number of impression in admob increase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595147/if-i-am-testing-app-in-test-mode-will-the-number-of-impression-in-admob-increase)